# which of the following statement is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

> Let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence of functions which are continuous over $[0, 1]$
>   and continuously differentiable in $[0, 1]$. Assume that $|f_n(x)| \leqslant 1$ and that
>   $|f_n' (x)| \leqslant  1$   for all $x \in[0, 1]$ and for each positive integer $n$. Pick out the true statement:
>
> 1. $f_n$ is uniformly continuous for each $n$.
> 2. $f_n$ is a convergent sequence in $C[0, 1]$.
> 3. $f_n$ contains a subsequence which converges in $C[0, 1]$.

From my point of view all options are correct because  function derivative is bounded  and continuous, so function is uniformly continuous in $[0,1]$.
But I'm not sure about my answer because  my teacher give me $0$ mark on this question.
If anybody help me  I would be very thankful to him.

Comment: You did not say why you think (b) and (c) are correct.  If you said they are all correct, I would also  give you 0.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Take $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$ then $\{f_n\}_n$ is a sequence of of continuous (constant) functions  which satisfies the given conditions, that is  $|f_n(x)| \leqslant 1$ and 
$|f_n' (x)| \leqslant  1$   for all $x \in[0, 1]$ and for each positive integer $n$. What may we conclude about option 2.?

Note that $|f_n(x)| \leqslant 1$ and 
$|f_n' (x)| \leqslant  1$   for all $x \in[0, 1]$ and for all $n\geq 1$ imply that the sequence is equibounded and equicontinuous. For option 3. use [Ascoli-Arzelà Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).

Comment: but how its satisfies option b and option c,,,,@ robert Z

Comment: @lomber lego In fact my example says that option 2 is not correct.

Comment: pliz explain me in detail, im very weak in analysis@ robertZ

Comment: @lomber lego See my edited hint  and try to answer to 2. and 3. (your answer for 1. is correct).

Comment: there are two convergent sequence -1 and +1  but  still they are converging in C[0,1],,,so option b may be correct@ RObert Z,,,pliz  tell me im not still clearing

Comment: @lomber lego No, the sequence $(-1)^n$ is not convergent so (b) is FALSE. For (c) follow my hint about Ascoli- Arzela.

Comment: thanks a lot @ robert Z ,  now i  have clear  my doubt,,,,,

Comment: @lomber lego Well done. If you are new here, please take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour